# Missing inline helptext

Tags: custom-object, button-overrides, helptext

I've encountered the problem with the inline help text. I've it on my field called Label on a custom object. The problem is that when I'm overriding the New button for that object with the Aura component with LWC embedded this help text is missing. The tooltip is simply blank. Does anyone have an idea what may be the problem here and any solution for that?

Comment: Without zeeing some code, it's hard to tell exactly. If you [edit] your question to show some code, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @sfdcfox the thing is that I'm not changing anything related to this help text in the code, simply creating an object using the LWC component, etc. This field has inline text defined and in the case of overridden button it's missing after hovering it on the layout when it shouldn't